# removing extra column in a csv file while exporting data using python3

Tags: python-3.x, csv, export

I wrote a function in `python3` which merges some files in the same directory and returns a `csv` file as the output but the problem with `csv` file is that I get one extra column at the beginning which does not have `header` and the other rows of that columns are numbers starting from 0. do you know how I write the `csv` file without getting the extra column?

Answer (score 0):

you can split by `,`, and then use slicing to remove the first element.

example:

```py
original = """col1,col2,col3
0,val01,val02,val03
1,val11,val12,val13
2,val21,val22,val23
"""

original_lines = original.splitlines()
result = original_lines[:1]  # copy header
for line in original_lines[1:]:
    result.append(','.join(line.split(',')[1:]))

print('\n'.join(result))
```

Output:

```
col1,col2,col3
val01,val02,val03
val11,val12,val13
val21,val22,val23
```